# React native how to change the whole application text by changing the language?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have installed the i18n package https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n, which is working fine.

In my LanguageScreen, I am storing the chosen language in the Async Storage. This is also working fine, unfortunately, by switching the languages it doesn't reload the app translations. How to achieve that?

Here is my LanguageScreen:

```
const LANG_KEY = '@lang'

function LanguageScreen({ props, navigation }) {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('');
    
    const saveLanguage = (lang) => {
        cache.store(LANG_KEY, lang);
        i18n.locale = lang;
    };
    const readData = async () => {
        try {
          const userLang = await cache.get(LANG_KEY);
          if (userLang !== null) {
            setLanguage(userLang)
          }
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        readData()
    }, []);
    
    ...
    
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the language selection by the user gets handled by your app? Is it within that i18n library? If so you might focus on the library docs first, and see if you can get it to trigger _anything_ in your app at all (after initial load).